# SQL - CASE WHEN within STUFF function for conditional delimiter

Tags: sql, function, t-sql, rows, string-comparison

Long story short: I am trying to use a conditional delimiter in my STUFF() function.  For my data purposes, the values in the example below are in a series based on **the first two digits**.

```
| uniqueID   | value    |
| name1      | 110      |
| name1      | 111      |
| name1      | 112      |
| name1      | 113      |
| name1      | 120      |
| name1      | 121      |
| name1      | 130      |
| name1      | 131      |
```

A STUFF() function looks like this:

```
select t.uniqueid, stuff((select distinct ',' + v.value
    from #temp v
    where v.uniqueID = t.uniqueid
    for XML path ('')),1,1,'')
from #temp t
```

...which returns:

```
| uniqueID   | value                                  |
| name1      | 110, 111, 112, 113, 120, 121, 130, 131 |
```

Again, since internally we classify the above codes based on **the first two digits**, I would like a comma between values within the same series, and a unique delimiter (for example an @) between the last value in one series and the first value in the next series.

Ideal output:

```
| uniqueID   | value                                |
| name1      | 110, 111, 112, 113@120, 121@130, 131 |
```

My first thought to run the STUFF() as is and then search within the resulting string, but not sure if that's smart or even how to do that.

My second thought was maybe a CASE WHEN statement could be used in lieu of the delimiter ',' declaration within the STUFF(), but again I don't know how to compare one value to the next within the STUFF().

My last thought was maybe do a comparison before the STUFF() of the values and where the "series" ends, just add '+ @', which would get pulled in during the STUFF().

Any help or creative approach would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I think this works:

```
-- Set up temp table and test data
create table #values
(
    uniqueID varchar(100),
    value int
)

insert into #values
select 'name1', 110
union
select 'name1', 111
union
select 'name1', 112
union
select 'name1', 113
union
select 'name1', 120
union
select 'name1', 121
union
select 'name1', 130
union
select 'name1', 131
union
select 'name2', 110
union
select 'name2', 111
union
select 'name2', 112
union
select 'name2', 113
union
select 'name2', 114
union
select 'name2', 120
union
select 'name2', 130
union
select 'name2', 131
union
select 'name2', 132

go

-- Create CTE to add '@' to the last value in each series
with results (uniqueId, [value])
as
(
    select distinct
            v1.uniqueID
        ,case when v2.[value] is null then convert(varchar,v1.[value]) + '@' else convert(varchar,v1.[value]) end as [value]
    from #values v1
    left join #values v2 on v1.uniqueID = v2.uniqueID and v2.[value] > v1.[value] and v1.[value] / 10 = v2.[value] / 10
)

-- Return STUFFed final string (using reverse to remove trailing '@' without repeating code)
select 
     uniqueId
    ,reverse(stuff(reverse(replace(stuff((select distinct ',' + [value] from results r2 where r1.uniqueId = r2.uniqueId for xml path ('')),1,1,''),'@,','@')),1,1,'')) as [value]
from results r1

drop table #values
```

Result:

```
/-----------------------------------------------\
|uniqueId | value                               |
|---------|-------------------------------------|
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name1   | 110,111,112,113@120,121@130,131     |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
| name2   | 110,111,112,113,114@120@130,131,132 |
\-----------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: With only field reference tweaks this worked wonderfully.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked for you - I'm sure there is a more elegant way though!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using `lag()`:

```
select t.uniqueid,
       stuff( (select distinct
                      (case when left(prev_value, 2) = left(value, 2)
                            then ','
                            else '@'
                       end) + v.value
               from (select v.*, lag(v.value) over (partition by uniqueid order by v.value) as prev_value
                     from #temp v
                    ) v
               where v.uniqueID = t.uniqueid
               order by v.value
               for XML path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '')
from #temp t
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply.

I tried your solution and it is not working when multiple uniqueIDs are used or if the values happen to be out of order.

Comment: `drop table #temp

create table #temp (uniqueID varchar(100),value varchar(100))

insert into #temp values ('name1','110')
insert into #temp values ('name1','150')
insert into #temp values ('name1','121')
insert into #temp values ('name2','110')
insert into #temp values ('name2','140')
insert into #temp values ('name3','110')
insert into #temp values ('name3','150')`

Comment: `select t.uniqueid,
       stuff( (select
                      (case when left(prev_value, 2) = left(value, 2)
                            then ','
                            else '@'
                       end) + v.value
               from (select v.*, lag(v.value) over (order by v.value) as prev_value
                     from #temp v
                    ) v
               where v.uniqueID = t.uniqueid
               order by v.value
               for XML path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as [stuffstring]
from #temp t`

Comment: @JustinFreer . . . This should specifically work regardless of the ordering of the values, because it has an `order by` clause.  However, the query was missing the `partition by` for the unique id.

Comment: You're right. I forget I had taken the order by out during some tweaking. Apologies.